# how to get date from database and show in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have Date of birth of student in database. On edit. I want to show that date in the DOB input. That input have bootstrap datetimepicker also. Date is not showing in input.

```
<input type="text" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" class="form-control" value="<?php echo ($data) ? $data['birthdate'] : ''; ?>">

if ($('#birthdate').length > 0) {

    $('#birthdate').datetimepicker({

        defaultDate: new Date(),

        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',

        maxDate: moment()

    });

}
```

This is the output i am getting on edit.
[Output Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOu9J.png)

Comment: Have you included all necessary js/scripts for datetime picker. And, is it the right way here in `value="<?php echo ($data) ? $data['birthdate'] : ''; ?>"`??

Comment: Script is working fine. When i click the input. datetimepicker shows up. But i want to show previously added date from database to show in this input and then let user select new date if he wanna update. but old date is not showing in input. thats the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use date inside new Date

```
 if ($('#birthdate').length > 0) {

   $('#birthdate').datetimepicker({

      defaultDate: new Date("<?php echo ($data) ? $data['birthdate'] : ''; ?>"),

      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',

      maxDate: moment()

 });

}
```

Comment: Not worked. Shows 000-00-00 in the input and datetimepicker calender also doesn't show

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php echo ($data) ? $data['birthdate'] : ''; ?>
```

To

```
<?php isset($data['birthdate']) ? echo $data['birthdate'] : ''; ?>
```

Since `$data` is an array, it can't be echoed.

Comment: I have this in the top of the page. 
$data = (isset($this->updateData)) ? $this->updateData : false;

Comment: But, As far I know, this `<?php echo ($data) ? $data['birthdate'] : ''; ?>` is WRONG @AaqibMehran

Comment: But this is working for all the other fiels like firstname, lastname etc. Problem is with only dates. some problem because of datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#birthdate").datepicker("setDate", <?php echo ($data) ? $data['birthdate'] : ''; ?>);
```